# libtoolize: error: cannot list files

Tags: gcc, autoconf, automake, libtool

I was installing libtool 2.4.6 and ran into the following problem:

```
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.6, revision 2.4.6,
libtool: but the definition of this LT_INIT comes from revision .
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from revision 2.4.6
libtool: of libtool 2.4.6 and run autoconf again.
Makefile:1261: recipe for target 'libltdl/loaders/libltdl_libltdl_la-preopen.lo' failed
```

In an effort to fix this issue and after looking around on google, I executed the following command to recreate aclocal.m4. however, I got "cannot list files" error:

```
[server]#  autoreconf --install
libtoolize:   error: cannot list files: '/var/tmp/work/libtool-2.4.6.i386/share/libtool/build-aux'
autoreconf: libtoolize failed with exit status: 1
```

the directory was there and can be listed with ls command:

```
[server]#  ls -l /var/tmp/work/libtool-2.4.6.i386/share/libtool/build-aux
total 0
```

Any idea?

Comment: it's a perl program. you just omitted the most important line. what is line 339 and how that subroutine is called?(the thing similar to `sub function {`)

Comment: anyways, it doesn't change the fact that you have your permission denied. i guess you need `sudo autoreconf --force --install`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to get over the permission issue after logged in as root. but now I got:

#  autoreconf --install
libtoolize:   error: cannot list files: '/var/tmp/work/libtool-2.4.6.i386/share/libtool/build-aux'
autoreconf: libtoolize failed with exit status: 1
#  ls -l /var/tmp/work/libtool-2.4.6.i386/share/libtool/build-aux
total 0

Comment: do as i said, use `sudo`. logging into `su` and using `sudo` have subtle difference that may or may not influence it

Comment: In our Solaris environments, we don't have sudo installed nor RBAC. we have only plain root access... I removed the entire previous libtool source directory and start over as root user. I thought that should guarrantee the consistency. what can be the causing this issue?

Comment: you should have mentioned solaris. in solaris it should be `pfexec`. never log in as `su` before you pick up bad habit. if people around you all do that, it's either you are not lucky, or i probably don't use solaris long enough. about your question, did you look at: http://trac.netlabs.org/ports/ticket/66?

Answer (score 2):

this was cause by the line in libtoolize script:

```
        test -n "`{ cd $my_dir && ls; } 2>/dev/null`" \
            || func_fatal_error "cannot list files: '$my_dir'"
```

I don't know why it interpret a empty directory as "cannot list files"
the issue can be overcome by replacing the above line with:

```
    cd $my_dir && ls || func_fatal_error "cannot list files: '$my_dir'"
```